# Koin sharing instances between modules

Tags: android, dependencies, code-injection, koin, koin-scope

I'm using the Koin library for an Android project.
I want to share some instances between modules since they are used a lot throughout the application.
For instance:

```
val moduleA = module {
    scope(named<FragmentA>()) {
        scoped { FirebaseFirestore.getInstance() }

        scoped { LocalDatabase.getInstance(App.sContext) }
        scoped { NetworkDataSourceA(get()) }    
    }
}

val moduleB = module {
        scope(named<FragmentB>()) {
            scoped { FirebaseFirestore.getInstance() }

            scoped { LocalDatabase.getInstance(App.sContext) }
            scoped { NetworkDataSourceB(get()) }    
        }
    }
```

As we can see from the following modules the `FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()` and the `LocalDatabase.getInstance(App.sContext)` are the same between both modules. 
Is there a way where I can declare lets say a `moduleC` that contains `FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()` and the `LocalDatabase.getInstance(App.sContext)` and then call it on the `moduleA` and `moduleB`?

Comment: Yes, you can do this by create and close scope. Can you please add FragmentA or FragmentB code. so that I can add my answer based on your code.

Answer (score 1):

- You can do this by creating scope. Though I didn't tried.

  ```
  val moduleA = module {
  scope(named("CommonScope")) {

  scoped { FirebaseFirestore.getInstance() }
  scoped { LocalDatabase.getInstance(App.sContext) }

  scoped { NetworkDataSourceA(get()) }   
  scoped { NetworkDataSourceB(get()) }  

    }
  }
  ```
- Now, create your scope in your FragmentA using below line.(
  also same for FragmentB for NetworkDataSourceB)

  ```
  private val commonScope = getKoin().getOrCreateScope("scope1",named("CommonScope"))
  val networkDataSourceA = commonScope.get<NetworkDataSourceA>()
  ```
- And In `onDestroy` method

  ```
  commonScope.close()
  ```

  For more detail check [koin documentation](https://beta.insert-koin.io/docs/2.0/documentation/koin-core/index.html#_what_is_a_scope) (8th point)

Comment: is there a way to insert that common scope inside the `moduleA` and `moduleB` directly?

Comment: Still, I didn't find that way. I also want that solution.

Answer (score 0):

As per the koin documentation,

> By default, all scope fallback to resolve in main scope if no definition is found in the current scope.

I would suggest putting the dependencies in the parent scope whiz.

```
val appModule = module {
     single { FirebaseFirestore.getInstance() }
     single { LocalDatabase.getInstance(App.sContext)} 
}
```

And load this module in your **startKoin** so that it's available everywhere.