# Koin 2.0 with Nested-Scope or SubComponent concept

Tags: android, dependency-injection, koin, koin-scope

Is there any way to implement Dagger's SubCompoent concept on Koin?

The thing that i want to do is using instance from parent scope's one.

**app_modules.kt**

```
val favoriteModule = module {
    scope(named<FavoriteFragment>()) {
        scoped { GetFavoriteMovies(get()) }
        scoped { FavoriteVMFactory(get(), get()) } // This need 'MovieEntityMovieMapper'
    }
}

val popularModule = module {
    scope(named<PopularFragment>()) {
        scoped { GetPopularMovies(get()) }
        scoped { PopularVMFactory(get(), get()) } // This need 'MovieEntityMovieMapper'
    }
}

val searchModule = module {
    scope(named<SearchFragment>()) {
        scoped { SearchMovies(get()) }
        scoped { SearchVMFactory(get(), get()) } // This need 'MovieEntityMovieMapper'
    }
}

val mainModule = module {
    scope(named<MainActivity>()) {
        scoped { MovieEntityMovieMapper() }
        // this ImageLoader also injected by Fragments
        scoped<ImageLoader> { (activity: Activity) -> GlideImageLoader(activity) }
    }
}
```

Using Dagger, this can be done by SubComponent or Component Dependency.

But in Koin(especially 2.0), i cant not find way.

Some answer said use 
`GlobalContext.get().koin.getScope("Parent").get<>()`.

https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/513

[Koin sharing instances between modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56721048/koin-sharing-instances-between-modules)

but i dont think it's not a clean approach and a dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://github.com/beyama/winter which is inspired by Koin but has child graphs that can be used like Dagger's subcomponents. Winter has been used in production for some major apps with several million installs for a few years now. I hope it is ok to post an example here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.prosiebensat1digital.seventv
Disclaimer: I know the author and have been using his library myself since its release. So far it has been stable in my experience.